# Ripple paper wallaet from Rippley (https://ripply.eu/) code check / safe?

Tags: wallet, ripple, paper-wallet

This question is about Ripple, but I hope it's still okay to ask this question on Bitcoin StackExchange:

I am eager to put my Ripple in a paper wallet, and from searching the web I found Rippley.eu (https://ripply.eu/).

I was wondering if anyone has done a code check of this website, and can verify that it's safe to use for generating paper wallets for Ripple storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.ripplepaperwallet.com that should be safe.  If you can disconnect it from the internet and still generate an address in your browser while offline, then yes it is safe.

Comment: This is a seriously bad quantifier for safe. An "offline" paper wallet generator can still make deterministically backdoored keys without ever needing to communicate this information in any way. Don't trust your money to random websites mentioned on stack exchange.